# Suggestions to improve and learn better chess

Tags: learning, online-chess

I am an average player of chess with chess rating of **1750** max and average around **1600**. in Blitz on chess.com. I haven't read/learned about any specific openings. I just do play-lose-learn strategy.
I want to improve my rating at-least to the level of Candidate master but failed. As far as I know, the rating can be improved by learning the opening strategies & mid/end game strategies but I don't know where to start.
Kindly suggest me to how to improve the game, what to learn and where to learn, better websites, books etc.
Thanks.

Comment: Since you mention you play on chess.com: have you tried doing their lessons? They have lots of them on openings, strategy, and endgames, all of them being topics which candidate masters should know.

Comment: @itub yes. they have. but it needs subscription after few lessons. that I don't have.  hence I was looking for open-source/free resources. thanks

Comment: you could try lichess, it also has lessons and it's completely free.

Comment: YouTube has better content for learning than chess.com lessons which I've found to be mediocre except maybe for beginners.  Check out the St. Louis Chess club.  They have many excellent hour-long lectures by titled players that provide a great deal of insight into the game.